# Use preprocessed standard output in for loop without creating a file to read from

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

```
_id                      state    flag  pro prio attempt user   enqueued            age                 runtime     worker name
------------------------ -------- ---- ---- ---- ------- ------ ------------------- ------------------- ----------- ------ --------------------------------
5ef9b05ef491ab1b5b00f356 error    ....   0% 000    1/  1 xxx  2020-06-29 11:11:58 0:16:19             0:01:35            Loader
5ef9b06e9879a928038cce45 error    ....   0% 000    1/  1 xxx  2020-06-29 11:12:14 0:16:03             0:01:21            Loader
```

I receive this output from my system which takes care of a data pipeline. Jobs with "error" state should be restartet with a single command. The command would look like this: `coco --restart 5ef9b05ef491ab1b5b00f356`, so it means i need all _id´s.

I already came so far:

```
coco -l | cut -c1-25 | tail -2

5ef9b05ef491ab1b5b00f356 
5ef9b06e9879a928038cce45
```

This gives me the correct Id´s. I could write the id´s to a file and then read them line by line, but just taking the ids from `sdout` would be much better. It is possible to pipe this into a for loop? Something likes this?

```
coco -l | cut -c1-25 | tail -2 | {for i in sdout; do echo "$i"}
```

Comment: You can slightly improve your `cut` by passing a space delimiter, then picking up first field: `cut -d " " -f1`.

Comment: [bashfaq how to read a stream line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: thanks for the link, this works `coco -l | cut -c1-25 | tail -2 | while read -r id; do coco --remove-hard "$id"; done`